# Extension that blocks ads on Google Chrome 

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, adblock

I'd like to be able to block ads from showing while I browse the Internet on Google Chrome. I've looked, but I'm always nervous about installing add-ons.

Is there an extension that does this?

Comment: I'm always leery myself, that's why sticking with officially verfied or endorsed apps/add-ons is good practice

Comment: The problem my be yourself. Top chrome's addon is almost certificated so you can try. And on top of that, Google won't let any one use addon for an attack or hack your PC.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get Adblock functionality in Google Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/1589/is-it-possible-to-get-adblock-functionality-in-google-chrome) -- although **wait**.. that's waaaay outdated. We should definitely update it or keep this one here.

Comment: I use the HOSTS file to block ads regardless of browser.

Answer (score 10):

### AdBlock

[AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom) (strange name, I know) has been *great* in my experience.

[image]

Comment: Yep, I use it to block reddit's `next page` link too. Great for limiting my procrastination.

Answer (score 7):

### Adblock Plus

[Adblock Plus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cfhdojbkjhnklbpkdaibdccddilifddb?hl=en&hc=search&hcp=main) is not affiliated with AdBlock in any way, but works just as well for removing ads.

[image]